# pandas dataframe to list(just care about data)

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

[image: click to show the pic]

how can i get the list like:

`[[2017-08-01,1.18263,1.18266,1.18109,1.18113],
......,
[2017-08-18,1.18263,1.18266,1.18109,1.18113]]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) returns the data as a numpy array, from there you can go to a list by adding `tolist()`

Comment: use df.values.tolist() i got this:
[[Timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00'), 1.18263, 1.18266, 1.18109, 1.18113, 1.18381, 1.18385, 1.17863, 1.17867, 1.1812761994752348, 1.1813188445315443],.....
how to remove the "Timestamp"

Comment: i have solve the problem,before tolist(), covert the columns type,thanks